# Oculus Browser Enter VR events

Tags: webvr, oculus, oculusgo

Are there any any events to listen for for when the browser has completed loading in VR?

I've seen this https://immersive-web.github.io/webvr/spec/1.1/#interface-vrdisplayevent

However

```
 window.addEventListener('onvrdisplayconnect', e => console.log('vr display connected'))
```

Isn't firing anything.

Answer (score 0):

`onvrdisplayconnect` is the name of the event listener property; the name of the event is just `vrdisplayconnect`. So you can do either:

```js
window.onvrdisplayconnect = e => console.log;

// Similar thing but you can have multiple listeners wired up at once.
window.addEventListener('vrdisplayconnect', e => console.log(e));
```

Most (all?) DOM events are named this way.

Note, WebVR has been superseded by WebXR. The new API has an event for a device changes, but typically you just start a session with `navigator.xr.startSession('immersive-vr')` and when the Promise resolves the session has started. Listen to the "end" event for when the session ends.